# Route any controller function except one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller named 'Details' and there are some functions.
I want to redirect user to /details/index, the url format is like /details/(:any).
But there is only one exception for a function /details/product.
I have tried like this

```
$route['(^(?!details/product)\S*)'] = 'details/all_product';
```

But it didn't work. How can i do this? What is the wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this using some other references.
solution is i cannot create any route configuration that will make exception dynamically. i just have to do it manually. The solution was

```
$route['details/product'] = 'details/product';
$route['details/(:any)'] = 'details/index';
```

I have to put that exception manually just before i declare the route rule for (:any).